# JavaScript copy paste cell values

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery

The following function gets the lastly clicked cell value and pastes it into the edit box `editBox`, in which the user can then edit the value. Whenever the user goes out of the editing box the value is copy/pasted back to the cell. Aside from that functionality, the cell that's focused gets overlighted (red color).

I've noticed that sometimes when a value is too large (big number of lines), the copy-paste thingy takes longer than expected : it should be almost live ( <1s ) but actually takes 3-5s.

**--- EDIT : JsFiddle added ---**

https://jsfiddle.net/k3nj33nu/5/

**---------------------------------------**

Any suggested performance improvements?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lastClicked;

    $(document).on('click', '.cell', function() {
        $('.editBox').val($(this).val());

        if (lastClicked != undefined && lastClicked != $(this).attr('name')) 
        {
            var lastCell = $(document).find("[name='" + lastClicked + "']");
            var newCell  = $(this);
            ChangeCellBorderColor(lastCell, "");
            ChangeCellBorderColor(newCell, "red");
        }
        lastClicked = $(this).attr('name');

        $('.editBox').keyup(function() {
            $(document).find("[name='" + lastClicked + "']").val($('.editBox').val())
        });
    });
});

function ChangeCellBorderColor(cell, colour)
{
    cell[0].style.borderColor = colour;
}
```

Comment: Move your keyup function outside document on click, you are attaching the listener for every time you click on cell, so you are setting same value a lot of times innecesarily

Comment: Does not really make any difference. thanks though!

Comment: Be careful that with copy paste with mouse won´t trigger the keyup. How large is the value? Can´t be able to replicate your 3 seconds

Comment: Can you please add HTML code too. Some of the JS code may not be required. If possible, please create runnable stack-snippet.

Comment: JsFiddle added.